# Issue while installing RStudio on EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, rstudio

I am adding a script into my EC2 user data (Amazon Linux) to install Rstudio 3.6.3 version.
When i do ./configure

command it shows this error: libcurl >= 7.22.0 library and headers are required with support for https.

curl version on the ec2 is 8.0.1

Tried multiple things like separately installing libcurl and other changes but still failing